# Jqplot multiples yaxis with the same scale

Tags: scale, jqplot

I draw some plots with Jqplot and on some of them, I've 2 yaxis.

I would like to know if it is possible to specify that both axis have the same scale ?

I can't use only one axis because I plot different values but with the same unit.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the same **min**, **max** values for both your yaxis.You can also set **tickInterval** and **numberTicks** options to be sure of having two similar yaxis.

PS : Please see [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis) for more options about Axis.